# Number format, writting1000 instead of 1e+03

Tags: r, numbers, format

i wrote code to get relative frequency.number format had changed in output

```
OBD=read.csv("OBD.csv",header = TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
RF1=OBD$Engine_speed
range(RF1)
breaks = seq(0, 2800, by=200)
breaks
RF1.cut = cut(RF1, breaks, right=FALSE)
RF1.freq = table(RF1.cut)
cbind(RF1.freq)
```

please find my output below. how to get this in a general number format?

```
                        RF1.freq
[0,200)                     3333
[200,400)                     61
[400,600)                   1810
[600,800)                  13628
[800,1e+03)                 2936
[1e+03,1.2e+03)             4446
[1.2e+03,1.4e+03)           7815
[1.4e+03,1.6e+03)           9991
[1.6e+03,1.8e+03)          12658
[1.8e+03,2e+03)             6762
[2e+03,2.2e+03)             9963
[2.2e+03,2.4e+03)           3805
[2.4e+03,2.6e+03)           5196
[2.6e+03,2.8e+03)            294
```

Thanks
KP

Answer (score 0):

You could use :

```
format(df$col , scientific = F)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `options(scipen = 5)`